# Posts that have tagged my Page don't show up with API call

Tags: facebook-graph-api, restfb

I have a Facebook Page created for my service [here](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Rowz/265813166783408). The name of the page is Rowz.

There are some posts on the page by users who have tagged the Page in posts on their own walls. Those posts show up on the Rowz Page timeline. In the Graph API for Page there is a field 'tagged' which I assumed would get me these posts but the same doesn't work.

Is there a way to fetch those posts that have tagged Rowz in them?

Answer (score -1):

According to the [documentation for page object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) in graph API, `tagged` connection gets you the required result:

> name: `tagged`
>   description: The photos, videos, and posts in which the `Page` has been
>   tagged.
>  permission: any valid `access_token` or user
>   `access_token`.
>  returns: a heterogeneous `array` of `Photo`, `Video` or
>   `Post` objects.

You can test it here using graph API explorer (using the page ID mentioned in the question): https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=265813166783408%2Ftagged

It works fine for me.

You may also consider using FQL for it. Query [stream_tag](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream_tag/) table using a query something like this:

```
SELECT post_id,actor_id FROM stream_tag WHERE target_id=265813166783408
```

After this, you can iterate over `post_id` and query `stream` table for `message` field.

Comment: I have used the same graph explorer link. If you see the Facebook Page the first post is 'Rowz what's up?'. The graph API explorer doesn't show that post but posts like those are the ones I want.