# Facebook API: Posts that a page was tagged in

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8741144/posts-that-have-tagged-my-page-dont-show-up-with-api-call), which doesn't work and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23517747/facebook-api-see-posts-which-have-tagged-my-facebook-page), **but** the [Graph API Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed) says:

> /{page-id}/tagged shows the posts that this page was tagged in and the
>   'posts to page'

So that would lend me to think that any public posts that tag a particular page should show up as a response to this API call:

```
FB.api(

    '/{page-id}/tagged', 
    { 
        access_token : "{fake-access-token}",
        limit: 10 
    }, 
    function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
);
```

(switching out the placeholders for actual data, of course)
But only the 'posts to page' are showing up, not the posts tagged by other users.

I'd be very grateful for some insite.

Comment: File a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: After looking at the current bugs, it seems this issue has already been submitted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28159087/facebook-api-posts-that-a-page-was-tagged-in

However, I think my description is somewhat more concise, so I've added a link to this post in the comments.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that I pasted the link to this page. Here's the link to the Facebook bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/836100296416951/